# is there a way to make this code more terse?

Tags: python

Given a list of items, and a map from a predicate function to the "value" function, the code below applies "value" functions to the items satisfying the corresponding predicates:

`my_re0 = re.compile(r'^([a-z]+)$')
my_re1 = re.compile(r'^([0-9]+)$')
my_map = [
    (my_re0.search, lambda x: x),
    (my_re1.search, lambda x: x),
    ]

for x in ['abc','123','a1']:
    for p, f in my_map:
        v = p(x)
        if v:
            print f(v.groups())
            break`

Is there a way to express the same with a single statement?

If I did not have to pass the value returned by the predicate to the "value" function then I could do

`for x in ['abc','123','a1']:
    print next((f(x) for p, f in my_map if p(x)), None)`

Can something similar be done for the code above? I know, maybe it is better to leave these nested for loops, but I am just curious whether it is possible.

Comment: Is it always going to be `lambda x: x`? Seems kind of pointless.

Comment: of course not. this is only an example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit less terse than Nate's ;-)

```
from itertools import product

comb = product(my_map, ['abc','123','a1'])
mapped = ((p(x),f) for (p,f),x in comb)
groups = (f(v.groups()) for v,f in mapped if v)
print next(groups), list(groups) # first match and the rest of them
```

Comment: this is a good one. these lazy iterators allow you to get closer to the functional style of programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
[f(v.groups()) for x in ['abc','123','a1'] for p, f in my_map for v in [p(x)] if v]
```

You said more terse, right? ;^)

Comment: wait, but does the loop over my_map terminate when a predicate is found?

Comment: No.  You would only be able to use this with pure functions - those without side effects.

Comment: A `where` keyword?  What do you think this is, Haskell? :^p  Just because that's where list comprehension syntax came from...

Answer (score 0):

here is my version:

`for x in ['abc','123','a1']:
    print next((f(v.groups()) for p, f in my_map for v in [p(x)] if v), None)`

this version does not iterate over the whole `my_map` but stops as soon as the first successful mapping is found.